# C++ Style : guidelines for adding a type into the namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, styles

Is there a style guideline as to when a class is used "enough" such that adding it into the namespace of a source file is warranted (e.g. "using std::string")?

I know this is somewhat a matter of personal preference, but I don't like that I feel like I'm doing this semi-arbitrarily at the moment (e.g. whenever I start to get tired of typing std::string or whatever else, and not uniformly across files).

Up to now, I've rarely done this add all (by explicitly stating the namespace in every usage), but after a certain point it does start to hurt the readability (lines become >80 characters faster, seeing std::string all over template definitions, etc). With some boost classes, these things can get pretty long as well (boost::gregorian::date_duration)

Comment: You should be doing this inside the functions in which you need it.

Comment: FWIW, you can do `namespace bg = boost::gregorian;` and then it becomes `bg::date_duration`.

Comment: +1 for @RMF. Use `using` never except for ADL control or unhiding, but use namespace aliases freely.

Comment: Do what you like in a source file, but avoid `using` at namespace-scope in headers.